# Is using a trusted SMTP provider necessary for emails to a single user

Tags: asp.net, azure, smtp

I've heard it's good to use third party SMTP providers to send your bulk emails because they have a higher trust rate and can avoid the pitfalls of being blacklisted.

Does this still apply for emails to a single user? I.E I need 100% guarentees my:

Registration, activation, forgot my password emails e.t.c (which only go to on person) will arrive at the recipient. Can I just use SMTP from my own server?

Using Azure hosting and ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption often repeated by Azure folks, is that Azure will eventually get blacklisted as a platform for sending out emails, because of its potential to be a spam platform.

Because spammers may abuse it and get it black-listed with email servers worldwide, it is suggested by Azure folks, that you utilize a "better" email sending system than your own SMTP servers.

It doesn't matter how many people you send your emails to.  The worry is, that Microsoft is not doing anything to stop spammers from sending emails from Azure and thus the risk exists that in a few months or years from now (or maybe it's already happening), your registration emails to your users as well as emails from anyone else running on Azure will go directly into recipients' spam folders .

Comment: Thanks Igorek, do you have any suggestions for a third-party system?

Comment: Looks like there is sendgrid.com :-) Expensive though :(

Comment: I do.  We use Amazon's SES to send out AzureWatch alerts.  We send out thousands of alerts on a daily basis, and our costs are very very low in comparison to sendgrid's of the world

Comment: Thanks that's useful! I can't seem to figure out how to PM you, do you recommend Azure as a hosting service? I've heard it's much more expensive than Amazon.

Comment: I do, but I am biased :) igor@paraleap.com

Answer (score 1):

There are **no** 100% guarantees in email delivery. Each email provider has their own internal methods on decided whether or not to deliver an email.

The IP of your SMTP server is one criteria, and yes your reputation matters... and once you abuse that privilege it is a hard thing to recover from. There are a number of other criteria that email providers use when deciding to mark your message as SPAM or not. This can include if you send email too fast or perhaps if too many of your emails bounce due to invalid addresses. Domain reputation and the activity of your email recipients matters too (does everyone just delete your message without opening, or is everyone flagging you as SPAM?).

Sending email from your own SMTP server should be safe as long as you haven't participated in bad email practices in the past. I have personally seen to negative effects of attempting to do mass-email from your own server, and that *will* impact even transactional emails that your website may generate.

Depending on your 3rd party SMTP server, yes they could be more successful than you. If you have not done any bad email practices in the past, though, your own should be fine as well.  It does help to use a service though where they specialize in email delivery and maintaining your sending reputation. Either way, nothing will guarantee 100% delivery.